# Firebase App Configure failing IOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

We have been working on an IOS app for the past couple of days. We implemented firebase and everything worked fine. However recently a coworker changed the bundle identifier of the app. After that, the Firebase app would not configure and we would receive an error prompting us to configure firebase upon the first use of firebase.

We have tried downloading a new info.plist, making a new firebase app and downloading the new info.plist and deleting our entire project, migrating the code to a new project reinstalling the pods and creating a new firebase app with a new info.plist. We also tried creating a new Firebase Project. None of this has worked.

Any ideas as to what is happening or how to fix this?

edit: the configure code is run in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when I run into this issue it has something to do with where you're configuring the "Firebaseapp.configure()". Try placing it in your first view under viewDidLoad or app delegate. Have you tried that?

Comment: It is currently in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. I will update the question.

Comment: trying moving the configure to another spot. Try the first view controller in viewdidload. Tell me if that works.

Comment: Oh okay. that's strange. Make sure you're not using it twice anywhere in your code as well

Comment: you're problem boils down to the configuration being used twice or it's not being read at all when the app is launched. When it's not read, that means it's in a place where firebase is being called before it's even set up.